# Java webservice NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, web-services, service, mocking, soapui

I am generating a webservice stubusing this statement in java

```
 new TPFServiceStub(webserviceUrl);
```

I have created a mock service in soap UI at 8088.
The same URL I am passing in the webserviceUrl variable.
All the dependent jars are placed in axis_home.
I am getting this following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMDataSource
    at com.arcot.csso.credchangereportsvc.dao.CIWebserviceDAO.getServiceObject
```

Can you please help me out :)

Comment: What do you see when you use the verbose flag: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-use-verbose-option-while-running-a-java-applic.html

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is always a classpath issue. Make sure you have the library that contains class `org.apache.axiom.om.OMDataSource` in the classpath on the side where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the library/framework you've been using to implement your WebService endpoints uses Apache Axiom as SOAP Message Factory. So, you should make sure you have Axiom jar on your classpatch.

You can get the latest binary for Apache Axiom here: http://ws.apache.org/axiom/download.cgi

In case you've been yet another happy user of Maven you can simpply add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.11</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the axiom jar containing the OMDataSource class in your deployment classpath?