# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMNode

Tags: java, servlets, wso2-data-services-server

Im having error its says java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMNode

in my java web application. By the way im implementing the servlet to call the dataservice in wso2 data service.

Here's the full stack trace:

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class org.wso2.sample.RegisterpatientServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.wso2.sample.RegisterpatientServlet
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMNode
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.om.OMNode
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank You Please Help! Im having hard time in this..

Comment: It seems that JVM cannot find OMNode class.  Is OMNode library is set in the class path on the server?  Do you have the OMNode jar file? Check out https://ws.apache.org/axiom/userguide/ch02.html   "Once the Axiom binary is obtained by any of the above ways, it should be included in the classpath for any of the Axiom based programs to work. Subsequent sections of this guide assume that this build step is complete and axiom-api-1.2.19.jar and axiom-impl-1.2.19.jar are present in the classpath along with the StAX API jar file and a StAX implementation."

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489084/java-webservice-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to make this class available to your web application is to put the `axiom.jar` file in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: It helps! :) @MaVRoSCy

Answer (score 2):

The apache axiom library is not in your classpath. If you use maven, make sure that it is in your `pom.xml`. if it's there, make sure that it has the runtime scope: `<scope>runtime</scope>`.

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency to your project. (Change version as you want)

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.commons.axiom/axiom-impl/1.2.6
```